# Can Customcontrol event can be overriddden?

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-server-controls

I have a gridview customcontrol, for that paging event has defined in seperate class library. Can i write an paging event in my aspx.cs where i am using the customcontrol instead of calling that event from seperate class file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expose events from your custom control you can use them in your codebehind yes.

Already a bit older but it shows how to do it: 
[Creating a Custom .NET Web Control With Events](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/031023.htm).

I also found these tutorials to be interesting: [Developing Custom ASP.NET Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy.aspx).

Comment: @Bala: I added some extra links for you to check out.